# XQuery: are there any web servers providing this functionality?

Tags: php, xml, apache, xquery, aruba

I have been asked to realized a little web application dealing with a little quantity of data. They do not want to use a DBMS like MySQL so I have thought that it could be useful to manage data through XQuery and XML files. So I am asking you to tell me if there are some web hosting servers providers like ARUBA that have XQuery. There are some libraries for PHP-XQuery like Zorba but they need to load some .so files to run correctly and I don't know if I can upload that kind of files...thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are Amazon EC2 AMIs available for [eXist-db](http://www.exist-db.org) on EC2 if that is of interest?

eXist provides an XML Native Database and XQuery engine (and more) coupled with a Web Server

Comment: Yes, it sounds interesting but I don't know what it is...can you explain me?